# Apollo Client with different client instances for react

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

My Project needs to be implemented with two different graphQL clients.

I was trying to add the client instance as an option inside the useQuery hook. However that is not working and leads to infinite rendering and network calls.

```
const client1 = new ApolloClient({
        link: from([authLink, errorLink, httpLink]),
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
   
      });

const {data, error} = useQuery(GET_COLLECTIONS, {
                                 client: client1
                                  variables: variables
                         });
```

Is there anyway I can use two different instances on my React js project with Apollo client? In some cases, in a single component I will have to call two graphQL API. So I cannot use ApolloProvider wrapper which expect single client instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have access to the client, you can use the `.query` (or `.mutate`) method as described [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient/#ApolloClient.query).

You'd have to build your own hooks though if you want to have the same api as `useQuery` and `useMutation` (which is probably not feasible when using advanced options). With `useState` you can store the `called`, `loading`, `error` & `data` states and when the request promise resolves/rejects update the respective states.